# oracle error procedure pl-sql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, compiler-errors

I have to write a procedure which can add a row to a table under conditions: `noli`, `noco` and `notr` are keys in other tables so I have to make sure that they already exist. So I write this solution. Procedure compiled correctly but when I'm trying it, it give me error object invalid.

```
create or replace procedure insertAffectation
    ( noli2 affectation.noli%type
    , date_voy2 affectation.date_voy%type
    , noco2 affectation.noco%type
    , notr2 affectation%type )
is
    v_noli liaison.noli%type;
    v_date affectation.date_voy%type;
    v_noco conducteur.noco%type;
    v_notr train.notr%type;

begin

    begin
        select noli into v_noli from liaison where noli=noli2 ;
    exception
        when NO_DATA_FOUND then raise_application_error('-20000','noli does not exist');
    end;

    begin 
        select noco into v_noco from conducteur where noco=noco2;
    exception
        when NO_DATA_FOUND then raise_application_error('-20004', ' noco does not exist');
    end;

    begin
        select notr from train where notr=notr2;
    exception
        when NO_DATA_FOUND then raise_application_error('-20001', 'notr does not exist');
    end;

    select embauche into var_date from conducteur where noco=noco2;

    insert into affectation values(notr2,date_voy2,null,noco2,notr2);

end insertAffectation;
```

and the error output was:

```
execute insertAffectation('111254',TO_DATE('01/07/02','DD/MM/YY'),'5555','6666')
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object SYSTEM.INSERTAFFECTATION is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

Comment: can you show the table definition for affectation, specifically for the 3 %types used. `affectation.noli%type, 
affectation.date_voy%type, 
affectation.noco%type, `  and what is affectation%type on the paramater I don't see the column.

Comment: i missed it its affectation.notr%type

Comment: table affect: noli(char(6)) , date_voy(DATE), nbpass(number(3) can be null),  noco(char(4))  notr(char(4))

Comment: If the 3rd parameter is a number and you're passing it in as character.... `'5555'` perhpas failing a type conversion.  In combination with the missed field on the type perhaps?

Comment: i think its not the prob

Comment: Your procedure obviously did not compile successfully - open it in the tool you are using and you will see the exact error. You will notice error in this line: 'select notr from train where notr=notr2 ;' - you are missing INTO clause here.

Comment: @GoranStefanović is correct. This error is not in execution, but compiling. As the error states `SYSTEM.INSERTAFFECTATION is invalid`. Every tool, including the most basic like SQLPlus, should have things built in to view compilation errors. Adding `INTO` may fix the procedure, but if not you should check compilation.

Answer (score 0):

The options to resolve this Oracle error is:

```
 select embauche into **var_date** from conducteur where noco=noco2;
```

But you don't declare var_date, you declare v_date. Change it and the ORA probably has been resolved.